# Error during to run the command: gradle flywayRepair ... Caching disabled for task or how to restore the migration history table of flywaydb?

Tags: gradle, flyway

I have a project on Spring boot .  I use **flywaydb** when working with **postgresql** scripts.

a row has been deleted from the migration history table. now, when trying to add migrations, an error happens:

> Message    : ERROR: column "..." of relation "...." already exists

I would like to use the command

```bash
 gradle flywayRepair -i
```

**build.gradle**

```yaml
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.2.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
  
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.2.4"
}

flyway{
    url = 'jdbc:postgresql://..:5432/..'
    user = '...'
    password = '....'
    table = 'schema_history'
}
```

However, when running the command, I get an error

> Task :flywayRepair FAILED Caching disabled for task ':flywayRepair'
> because:   Build cache is disabled Task ':flywayRepair' is not
> up-to-date because:   Task has not declared any outputs despite
> executing actions. :flywayRepair (Thread[Execution worker for
> ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.025 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':flywayRepair'.  Error occurred while executing flywayRepair   Configuration with name
>   'compile' not found.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to restore the migration history table?